# Why won't this return the exact string I want?

Tags: java, swing

I want my result like these. If I click the finish button, a class will be added to a `umlClassList` (via `setName`) and `publicPrivate` ArrayLists in the `StoreData` class. Then I want to convert them to string and show them in a Text box area in the `GenCode` class, like `public ClassName{}`

I want to get the string `s3=s1+s2+s3` to the `textarea` in the `GenCode` class after calling `genCode()`  in the `StoreData` class, but why does it only return `{}`? I want to get  `public ClassName{}`

```
public class CreateUmlClass extends JFrame {

JRadioButton radio1Public = new JRadioButton("Public"); // Radio Button
JRadioButton radio2Private = new JRadioButton("Private");
JButton finish = new JButton("Finish");
JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
JButton clearAll = new JButton("Clear All");
JLabel classNameLabel = new JLabel("Class Name:");// Class name label
JLabel methodNameLabel = new JLabel("Method Name:");// Class name label
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
JTextField methodNameTextField = new JTextField(20);// Class Name Text Box
JTextField classNameTextField = new JTextField(20);// Class Name Text Box
private JFrame frame;

public CreateUmlClass() {
    super("Create class");

    this.setLocation(100, 100);
    // this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    add(classNameLabel);
    add(classNameTextField);


    group.add(radio1Public);
    group.add(radio2Private);
    add(radio1Public);
    add(radio2Private);
    add(methodNameLabel);
    add(methodNameTextField);
    add(finish);
    add(cancel);
    add(clearAll);


    Handler handle = new Handler();
    finish.addActionListener(handle);
    cancel.addActionListener(handle);
    clearAll.addActionListener(handle);

}

private class Handler implements ActionListener {
    String ClassName;
    StoreData obj = new StoreData();

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == finish) {
            ClassName=classNameTextField.getText();
            if (classNameTextField != null && (radio1Public.isSelected() || radio2Private.isSelected())) {
                obj.setName(ClassName);
                if (radio1Public.isSelected()) {
                    obj.CheckisPrivate(false);

                } else if (radio1Public.isSelected()) {
                    obj.CheckisPrivate(true);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Your class is stored");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "Class Name or/and access modifier cannot be empty.",
                        "Inane warning",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == cancel) {
            setVisible(false);
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == clearAll) {
            classNameTextField.setText(null);
            group.clearSelection();
            methodNameTextField.setText(null);              
        }
    }

}
}
```

**StoreData class**

```
public class StoreData {

    String name;
    static ArrayList<String> umlClassList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> publicPrivate = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void setName(String className) {

        umlClassList.add(className);

    }

    public void CheckisPrivate(boolean isPrivate) {
        if (isPrivate = true) {
            publicPrivate.add("Private");
        } else if (isPrivate = false) {
            publicPrivate.add("Public");
        }
    }

    public String genCode() {
        String s3="";
        for (int index = 0; index < umlClassList.size(); index++) {
            String s1,s2;
            s1=publicPrivate.get(index);
            s2=umlClassList.get(index);
            s3=s3+s1+s2;        
        }
        return s3+"{"+"}";

    }

}
```

**GenCode class**

```
public class GenCode extends JFrame{

    JLabel genedCode = new JLabel("The generated code:");
    StoreData data = new StoreData();
    String finalCode =data.genCode();
    JTextArea codeBox = new JTextArea(finalCode,5,30);
    JButton okbtn = new JButton("OK");
    JButton cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    Handler handle = new Handler();

    private JFrame frame;
    public GenCode(){
        super("The Generated Code");
        setSize(200, 900);
        setLocation(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());


        //add(codeBox); 
        add(codeBox);
        codeBox.setVisible(true);
        codeBox.setEditable(false);
        add(okbtn);
        add(cancel);


        //add(codeBox,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cancel.addActionListener(handle);

    }
    private class Handler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==cancel){
                setVisible(false);
            }
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Does it return "{}" instead ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to do, but `if (isPrivate = true)` is certainly wrong. You probably mean `if (isPrivate == true)` (or better `if (isPrivate)`).

Comment: Do you want the concatenation or the arithmetic sum? For the latter, see this possible duplicate: [using eval in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java)

Comment: String concatenation inside a loop should always be done using a `StringBuilder`

Comment: to me it looks like both of the lists are empty, you're never adding anything to them.

Comment: i want the result like this in text area:
public ClassName{};

Comment: Update your question to clarify your intent.

Comment: `if (isPrivate == true) {...} else if (isPrivate == false) {...}` Conditions always evaluate to true with java, so you can write `if(isPrivate) {...}`: it means `if(isPrivate == true)`. Then, don't use an `else-if`, if a boolean is not `true`, of course it is `false`. You can write `if(isPrivate) {...} else {...}`

Comment: @Jixi I have edit my post and added a class.
if i click finish button. Then a class will add in to arraylist and call setName Method and publicPrivate method. Then i want to convert them in to string and show it in Text box area
like:
public ClassName{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
public String genCode() {
    String s3="";
    for (int index = 0; index < umlClassList.size(); index++) {
        String s1,s2;
        s1=publicPrivate.get(index);
        s2=umlClassList.get(index);
        s3=s3+s1+s2;        
    }
    return s3+"{"+"}";

}
```

can be simplified to

```
public String genCode() {
    String s3="";
        String s1,s2;
        if(umlClassList.size()>0)
        {
            s1=publicPrivate.get(umlClassList.size()-1);
            s2=umlClassList.get(umlClassList.size()-1);
        }
        s3=s3+s1+s2;        
    return s3+"{"+"}";

}
```

So the reason it returns "{}" is because "umlClassList" is empty and you dont update s1 and s2. You can check this by

```
if(umlClassList.size()==0) System.out.println("umlClassList is empty" );
```

Comment: I've got a syntax error on the `}` after the line ` s3=s3+s1+s2;`

Comment: I have changed the code but code another error again;(
it said String s1,s2 are not initialized.

Comment: can i intialize s1,s2 be null in these situation?

Comment: yeah String s1 = "",s2 = "";

Comment: Thats because your umlCLassList is empty.

Comment: i have entered the class name and the access modifier then click the generate code button. But it still output {} only..